# Rails & Handlebars: bad URI error for template URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, handlebars.js, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

In an older project I used this Handlebars template:

```
script id='user-form-template' type='text/x-handlebars-template'
  = simple_form_for User.new, method: 'post', url: '/users/{{id}}' do |f|
    = hidden_field_tag :_method, '{{method}}'
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :email
    ...
```

This created a form within a Handlebars template with this action:

```
action="/users/{{id}}"
```

I used it to create new *(leave id blank, set _method to POST)* and edit existing *(set id, set _method to PATCH)* users.

In my new project (Rails 5.2.1) I get a **URI::InvalidURIError** message:

```
bad URI(is not URI?): /users/{{id}}
```

Is there a better way to build a template with a form? I would like to keep SimpleForm to automatically create the bootstrap form HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the template to

```
= simple_form_for User.new, method: 'post', data: { url: '/users/{{id}}' }
```

I then change the `data-url` back to `url` after replacing the placeholders in the template:

```
$('form').attr('action', $('form').data('url'));
```

Not the best solution, but I can work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing `simple_form_for User.new`, instead of `simple_form_for @existing_user`, I'd bet that you need to remove the `/{{id}}` portion of the URL. If you are trying to create a new user you want to post to just `/users`.

Comment: In my previous project I could use the form for new and existing users which worked great. Without {{id}} I could only use it for new users, since I cannot add it with Handlebars. SimpleForm uses User.new to get model information, the URL doesn't matter. The brackets are the only problem in this case.